# Auto clustering in hazelcast

Tags: java, load-balancing, hazelcast

I tested with the hazelcast-default.xml,

What is happening is I have started a node 192.X.1.1 with port as 5701 and it becomes up and works like a fly,

Mean while, I started a node 192.X.1.2 with port 5701 and I wonder It does a mapping and join together, How to avoid that,

Is the param cluster.min setting to '1', solves the problem???

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, not sure I understood your question.

Comment: The data is unnecessarly replicated to other port...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that by cluster min setting you mean hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size . That is unrelated to this issue. This property simply requires an x number of nodes to join the cluster before starting your application.

What you are looking for depends on whether you are using multicast or TCP-IP to discover nodes.
See this book for details: http://hazelcast.com/resources/mastering-hazelcast/

In case of multicasting you need to set groups, and add the nodes to different groups.

You could also simply define interfaces such as:
                
                    192.168.24.*

with the range of IP you want to by accepted by your cluster.

Finally if you are using TCP-IP you need to define the ip of the nodes that will join your cluster.
A simple example being :

```
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="false" />
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <hz:members>192.168.0.1</hz:members>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>
```

(Example shown are using spring configuration)

Comment: how to disable it??? so that I will never get join to any of my other ports in the network

Comment: try setting both multicast enabled and tcp-ip enabled both to false, it should not connect to any other node/instance. alternatively enable tcp-ip and set <hz:members>127.0.0.1</hz:members> which will allow connections only to hazelcast instances on the local machine